# What causes an illegal offset in the makeAlias function of laravel 5.5 within this package implementation?

Tags: laravel-5, routes, package, model-binding

I am making packages for the first time in Laravel (v5.5).  Unfortunately, the Route Model Bindings are giving me trouble.  At first, I was receiving the id number raw without the model, and I realized that I had to force the package routes through the 'web' middleware grouping.

When I add the 'web' middleware grouping, I can see that laravel tries to load the model, but I receive an **"Illegal offset type in isset or empty"** in the first line of the `Container->makeAlias` method.

I have tried using custom binding loaders defined in the ServiceProvider using `Route::model( $class, $closure )`, but the error occurs before the loader is called.  I've even tried moving this declaration from the ServiceProvider->boot method to the ServiceProvider->register method, just in case it is an order of operations issue.

I have tried adding a binding to the app by calling `$this->app->bind` inside the ServiceProvider, but this has had no effect.

I'm going to post the relevant code below, and I appreciate any insites that you may have! Thank you in advance!

### Some Facts

#### The route

We are loading the url: `http://127.0.0.1/profiles/1/edit` for this test.

#### Operation without bindings

When no bindings or middleware are applied, and the url above is called, I can safely load the model from within the function manually and return the view.  This indicates that the package is correctly loaded into the main application container.

#### The model can load in Tinker

To verify the model and database connection, we use tinker and run the command `\Clemence\Profiles\Profile::find(1)` to which the following is returned:

```
=> Clemence\Profiles\Profile {#777
     id: 1,
     name: "Clemence, Jared",
     address: """
       554 Christmas Tree Lane\n
       Bakersfield, CA 93306
       """,
     email: "jaredclemence@gmail.com",
     phone: "610-360-9558",
     created_at: null,
     updated_at: null,
     deleted_at: null,
   }
```

#### The stack trace

The `Route->performBinding` method is called with the following arguments:

```
[
   Closure, /* Presumably the loader */
   "1", /* the index that is passed into the route URL */
   Route /* A self reference back to the containing object */
]
```

after this, the Closure is called with

```
[
  "1",
  Route
]
```

from the Closure, `Application->make` is called, the argument named `$class` is passed another Closure with the following definition:

```
Closure {#97 ▼
  class: "Clemence\Profiles\ProfilesServiceProvider"
  this: ProfilesServiceProvider {#87 …}
  parameters: {▶}
}
```

lastly we end up in `Container->makeAlias` where the Exception is thrown, makeAlias is called with this Closure:

```
Closure {#97 ▼
  class: "Clemence\Profiles\ProfilesServiceProvider"
  this: ProfilesServiceProvider {#87 …}
  parameters: {▶}
}
```

### The Files

packages/clemence/profiles/src/routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get('/profiles/{profile}/edit', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@edit');
    Route::get('/profiles/create', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@create');
    Route::get('/profiles', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@showAll');
    Route::get('/profiles/{profile}', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@show');


    Route::post('/profiles/create', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@createWithFormData')->name('profile.create');
    Route::put('/profiles/{profile}', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@updateWithFormData')->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profoiles/{profile}', '\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController@destroy')->name('profile.delete');

    Route::get('/roles', '\Clemence\Profiles\RoleController@showAll');
    Route::get('/roles/{role_id}', '\Clemence\Profiles\RoleController@show');
    Route::get('/roles/create', '\Clemence\Profiles\RoleController@create');
});
```

packages/clemence/profiles/src/ProfilesServiceProvider.php

```
namespace Clemence\Profiles;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class ProfilesServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        $this->loadRoutesFrom( __DIR__ . '/routes.php' );
        if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
            $this->commands([
                \Clemence\Profiles\Commands\InstallProfiles::class,
                \Clemence\Profiles\Commands\PrepareEnvironmentForProfiles::class
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        $this->app->make(\Clemence\Profiles\ProfileController::class);
        $this->app->make(\Clemence\Profiles\RoleController::class);
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/migrations');
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/views', 'profiles');
    }

}
```

packages/clemence/profile/src/ProfileController.php

```
namespace Clemence\Profiles;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Clemence\Profiles\Profile;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Clemence\Profiles\FormTemplateData;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /*  ... collapsed ... */

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Profile  $profile
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Profile $profile )
    {
        return dd( $profile );

        $formData = new FormTemplateData();
        $profile = Profile::find( $profile_id );

        $formData->setProfile( $profile );
        $formData->setFormActionMethod("POST");
        $formData->setDeleteButtonText("Delete Profile");
        $formData->setSubmitButtonText( "Update Profile" );

        $on_cancel_route_url = $formData->getNamedUrl('profile.delete');
        $on_submit_route_url = $formData->getNamedUrl('profile.update');
        $formData->setFormCancelUrl($on_cancel_route_url);
        $formData->setFormSubmitUrl($on_submit_route_url);
        return $this->editForm($formData);
    }

    /* ... collapsed ... */
}
```

packages/clemence/profile/src/Profile.php

```
namespace Clemence\Profiles;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### RESOLVED: SOLUTION UNKNOWN

I will post the steps that I took to find the resolution here for those who may find this post in the future.  I admit: I have no idea what fixed the problem.

#### What I did after asking the question

1. First and foremost, I got some sleep.  When I have been coding too long, I find that sleep solves most problems.
2. On waking, I realized that I have a machine with XDebug installed and I can literally step through the PHP code as it executes, so I booted up that machine and did the following:

   a. I moved the project to the local machine and opened it in NetBeans.

   b. I placed breakpoints at several places in the middle ware so that I could verify that the system was running.

   c. I changed the project config to run "as a website" and to load the url `http://localhost:8000/profiles/1/edit` as the start point.

   d. I clicked 'Debug Program' and stepped through the bootup, the route loading, the model binding, and watched it all happen step-by-step looking for any line of code or parameter that looked out of sorts.  I watched as the model was selected. I watched as it was passed the id `1` and asked to build the query. I watched as a collection of Profiles was returned (Oh! how excited I was to see the data I wanted sitting in that array and knowing that it was there but something would eventually block it, and I would find the block and release it!), and I watched as the collection was asked to return the first value. Then I watched as the parameter was set on the route.  Lastly, I watched as the command $kernal->terminate() ran....

Needlessly to say, I was very disappointed and confused. How could I be getting an error, if the Kernal is running to completion?

So, I looked at the browser window, and there in the browser window was the very information that I was looking for! The Profile had loaded.  I had changed nothing, and the Profile had loaded.

I moved the code back to the original machine, maybe it is an environment setting?  I ran the web query without debugging, and it loaded... no error!

So, I honestly don't know what happened.  I doubt that getting sleep helped the problem.

Maybe the Netbeans Debugger ran a cleanup service that fixed or patched a bad linkage?  I honestly don't know, but I do know that this problem is resolved, so I post this answer in the hopes that it helps someone in the future, and that it saves other people the time of needlessly looking for an unnecessary solution.